# How to make a NoDrag element inside the Jssor slider

Tags: javascript, slider, drag, jssor

How to make a NoDrag element inside the Jssor slider, if possible with examples in the sandbox^ ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div data-nodrag="true" ...`